# How many $n$ digit numbers formed from $n$ digits where a digit can be repeated twice?

Tags: permutations

So I had a problem saying how many $3$ digit numbers can be formed from the numbers $\{1,2,3\}$ where a digit can be repeated twice and the written answer was $18$.
When I tried to solve it myself by tree diagram and counting it was $24$ numbers. Then I tried by the techniques I know so I said the first digit would have $3$ possibilities the second one is also $3$ as we can repeat and the third one will be $2$ possibilities. So it will be $3\cdot 3\cdot 2=18$ but after some thinking I realised I am forgetting the numbers where there is no repetition which will be $3!$ added to the $18$ which make it $24$.
My question is am I right?And is there like a law for this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your answer is basically $24$, since you have $3^3 = 27$  possibilities totally, but you have to remove $111,222,333$, so that gives you $24$.

Comment: Yeah thats one of the ways i thought about it thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For general $n$ you can have $k$ pairs of same digits $k$ in $\{0,1,...,[n/2]\}$

You have to pick $n-2k$ digits that would appear once, then among rest of $2k$ digits you have to pick $k$ which will appear twice. Now you have to permute all those digits, it will be $n!/2^k$ cos you have to divide by $2$ for each pair, so total will be $$\sum_{k=0}^{[n/2]}(\frac{n!}{(2k)!(n-2k)!}\frac{(2k)!}{k!k!})\frac{n!}{2^k}=\sum_{k=0}^{[n/2]}\frac{n!^2}{(k)!^2(n-2k)!2^k}$$
Maybe someone can handle this sum to get a simple formula??

Comment: The formula is pretty complicated for me if you can tell me what k and n stand for in the problem i mentioned so i can generalise it to myself.Thanks for your answer.

Comment: What do you mean what n stands for? It is the number of digits. And k is the number of pairs of same digits so if you have 9 digits then k is at most 4, like 112233445. that's what [n/2] stands for cos 9/2=4.5

Comment: Oh i thought no. Of digits was n/2 thanks for your answer but just to make sure i understand k in my mentioned problem will be 1 and n will be 3 right?

Comment: After multiple reading your answer your approach seem to be right although i am having trouble linking between permutations and the summation formula (still learning,my bad) so i'll mark it as the answer Thanks for your time